# POST request not working using JQuery AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, post

I am trying to use JQuery AJAX to allow the user to input information into a form in a pop-over box, and then the information gets added to a MySQL database.
However, for some reason, when I use the JQuery AJAX functions -- I've tried both $.post() and $.ajax() -- to POST the data, it does not get POSTed. Instead I get error messages of "Undefined index" for all the fields I tried to POST (when I go to processNewAssignments.php, which is the URL I am POSTing to).  What am I doing wrong?

My JQuery AJAX function call when the user clicks to POST information is:

```
$.ajax({url: "[THIS CONTAINS THE REST OF THE URL]/processNewAssignments.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {max_grade: maxGradeValue, title: taskNameValue, due: dueDateValue}});
```

Or I have also tried:

```
$.post("[THIS CONTAINS THE REST OF THE URL]/processNewAssignments.php", 
        {max_grade: maxGradeValue, title: taskNameValue, due: dueDateValue});
```

My code for processNewAssignments.php (the URL the data is POSTed to) is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Process Assignments</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php 

    $maxgrade = $_POST["max_grade"];
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $due = $_POST["due"];
    $classID = $_SESSION["classID"];


    echo "hello!";
    echo $title . $classID . $due . $maxgrade;

    require("db.php");
    $query = "INSERT INTO assignments (title, assignmentID, classID, deadline, max_grade) VALUES ('$title', DEFAULT, '$classID', '$due', '$maxgrade')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

?>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead I get error messages of "Undefined index" for all the fields I
>   tried to POST (when I go to processNewAssignments.php, which is the
>   URL I am POSTing to). What am I doing wrong?

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find your posted variables by sending a ***second GET request***, i.e. entering the URL in the address bar.

If this is indeed the case, you SHOULD be getting `undefined index`, as you are not POSTing anything, hence the `$_POST` array is undefined.

To test your *ajax POST request*, you need to use Dev Tools (F12 on Chrome), choose the `Network` tab, and click on the post request that was made.

There you can see if the request was successful (200 response code), and what was the 
content of the response.

Comment: That makes so much sense!! Thank you!

Comment: I'd also recommend using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` or `$_GET` @user1516849

Answer (score 1):

You have specified 5 columns to **INSERT** into; but have only 4 values passed to it:

```
title, assignmentID, classID, deadline, max_grade
```

and your values:

```
'$title', DEFAULT, '$due', '$maxgrade'
```